# Why is this not proper overriding to implement the abstract method?

Tags: java

I am getting compile time error that I have not given implementation of abstract method; I am not sure what still needs my attention.

```
abstract class Bank{
int loan = 100;
int getInterest(int a);
}

class SBI extends Bank{
int loan = 200;
int getInterest(int a){
  return a;
}
}

class Test{

  public static void main(String[] s){
    Bank b = new SBI();
    System.out.println(b.getInterest(12));
    System.out.println(b.loan);
  System.out.println(new SBI().loan);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error

Comment: call super in your inherited class

Comment: It is nothing to do with "proper overriding".  The syntax error occurs in the abstract class, not the class that overrides / implements the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `Bank` as an abstract class. That doesn't make all methods declared in `Bank` abstract by default. You either need to provide an implementation or add the *abstract* keyword to the method

```
abstract int getInterest(int a);
```